# on waiting a thread it does not display the icon it should be displaying

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronized

I am trying to create a memory game.In that when the first and second button both have same images I set their images to null.Also to associate a value(ie an image) I have created class `UsingJButton` extending `JButton` class

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        if (game.timePassed == 0) {
            game.clock.start();
        }
        game.openButton(this);
        game.checkIfWon();
    }
}
```

This block of code calls `openButton()` method in another class.

```
public void openButton(UsingJButton b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (b.isEnabled() && !button1) {
        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(upperImages[b.value].getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50,
                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        b1 = new UsingJButton(b.row, b.col, this);
        b1 = b;
        button1 = true;
    } else if (b.isEnabled() && button1 && !button2 && ((b1.row != b.row) || (b1.col != b.col))) {
        synchronized (b) {
            b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(upperImages[b.value].getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50,
                    java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            button2 = true;
            try {
                b.wait(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (button1 && button2) {
        if (b1.value == b.value) {
            b1.setVisible(false);
            b.setVisible(false);
            flagCount += 1;
            paint();
            repaint();
        } else {
            b1.setIcon(null);
            b.setIcon(null);
        }
        button1 = button2 = false;
    }

}
```

My cause of concern is that in this snippet,

```
synchronized (b) {
    b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(upperImages[b.value].getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50,
            java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    button2 = true;
    try {
        b.wait(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I acquire lock on button `b` it duly waits for 2 seconds but the icon on the button is not displayed. I have declared my `ImageIcon[]` array in this class(in the class where `openButton()` is defined) whereas my buttons are of the `UsingJButtons` class.
The icon on button should be displayed as its important for the game.

Comment: Where are you calling `notify` to resume `wait` state?

Comment: Please post a complete testable code.

Comment: @Braj I am not using notify at all. I've read that for a thread to wait on an object it must gain its object's locks which I have gained and subsequently I have passed parameters of 2 seconds where after that time it stops waiting and the threads can compete for the object b